# Vkontakte API using OAuth does not work with Captcha

Tags: oauth, captcha, vk

Vkontakte API rejects requests with Captcha. [Here](https://api.vk.com/method/friends.add?uid=UID&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN) is the example what I do.

After the third request I get:

> Captcha error (14) - Captcha needed.

According to [documentation](https://api.vk.com/method/friends.add?uid=UID&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&captcha_sid=CSID&captcha_key=CKEY) it's sufficient to add `captcha_sid` and `captcha_key` parameters to the original requests and repeat the request.

But the response is still `Captcha error (14)`. Is it possible to work with Captcha and OAuth in Vkontakte API?

Comment: You sure so you pass "captcha_sid" and "captcha_key" correct way? I'm using them as well, the point is so "Captcha needed" error will repeat if sid or associated key(text from captcha) is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Captcha error

> Error code: 14
>
> Error text: Captcha needed

and captcha confirmation is required, when:

> action (e.g. sending a message) **is performed too frequently**, an API request may return "*Captcha needed*" error. After that a user needs to enter a code from the image and resend a request with a Captcha code input in the request parameters.

More information can be found [in their manual.](https://vk.com/dev/captcha_error)

If this error encounters, you need to process additionaly the following parameters from the response with the error message:

1. `captcha_sid` – captcha identifier;
2. `captcha_img` – a link to an image that will be shown to a user.

When user enters text from `captcha_img` you have to re-send the request adding following parameters:

1. `captcha_sid` – received ID;
2. `captcha_key` – text input you've gotten from user.

Do not forget to provide the valid access token as well, to make the user authorization, or the request would be declined with another type of error.