# VK.API: Captcha needed error

Tags: php, api, yii, vk

Are there any vkontakte api developers? I need your help!
I have an Yii application, running by cron (every 10 minutes) on dedicated IP.
It makes about 2.8 queries per second, but the "Captcha needed" error is still occurs...
Here is some info about error (russian) http://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%3A_Captcha_is_needed

Is there any way to make periodic queries to VK.API without risk of error?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It may be the same bug: http://vk.com/bugs?act=show&id=700787_3

Comment: Its was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280765/vkontakte-api-using-oauth-does-not-work-with-captcha.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, they should get you past the captcha:  http://deathbycaptcha.com/user/login

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is an anti-spam protection for some API methods in VK. You can send a lot of queries for getting information, etc., but methods like `wall.post` or `message.send` require to enter the captcha text to not allow spam-bots use VK API.

The only solution that I see is the usage of some captcha decoder services. Anyway, sending posts via cron is not a good idea at all.